# Etymology of "ruggit"?

Tags: etymology, slang

I did something stupid yesterday. "What a *ruggit*", I said to myself, meaning a stupid person. It occurred to me I hadn't heard the word for a while, so I looked it up, and found this source [here](http://www.odps.org/glossword/index.php?a=term&d=4&t=9667)

> Someone a little mentally ambivalent - i.e. 'simple.

But I noted the etymology given

> (Ruggits was the local 'special' school)

and I don't think it's right. I remember hearing the word in the mid-seventies, and the explanation I heard then was the same (a 10-year-old etymologist!), but I can't find any trace of a school with that name and don't believe it exists. Also, the source notes it as a south-western English term, and I was living in the south-east of England at the time; a school can't be 'local' to both areas.

A possibility is that it is related to the Manx [ruggit](http://glosbe.com/gv/en/noa-ruggit), new-born, but that seems a little farfetched. Or perhaps a corruption of [rugrat](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rugrat).

So, can anyone shed any light on the matter? Does anyone know why a *ruggit* is so called?

Comment: The articulation described (which is clearly an attempt to mimic a supposed or attributed speech defect--just try it) suggests that the first syllable of the underlying word could begin with d,t,r,dr or tr and end with or k, with a, o or u as the vowel. The only thing I found in a quick search was "rocket" for "idiot" in Glaswegian slang; but you'll be the best source for the local vernacular of your childhood.

Comment: Being ambivalent means you're simple? I don't know how I feel about that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Scots word *ruggy*  meaning 'clumsy in dress, loutish in appearance...loose, insecure, ramshackle ...untidy in dress... "Hair as ruggy's a collie's tail"' (selected from OED entry).
 Not sure how much of this applies to you (or your question) but it's the closest I could find.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at Google, I very quickly found:

> pt. pp. ruggit
>   n. [A bargain which takes unfair advantage of the seller. An unreasonably high profit.](http://www.scots-online.org/dictionary/read.asp?letter=R&CurPage=37)

This is from an online Scots dictionary, so it fits in with the context mentioned in the question.

Also from a Scots dictionary:

[RUGGIE, n. Also ruggy; rookie (Marw.). An undersized cod](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/)

[What do you think about this?](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/getent4.php?plen=14894&startset=96544611&dtext=dost&query=Rug) Using the same dictionary to look up 'Rug'

1. To break off (of) or tear away (a part of a body) from its normal position; to pull away (a garment or appurtenance). 
   Freq., to rug (the) hare (of the head).

Comment: Please don't add meta information, such as comments, into questions.

Comment: Let me reiterate: answers are not for conversations with yourself.

Comment: I have to add new bits as soon as they are deleted.